# Why such pattern can't be used in a member function?

Tags: c++

I've used a member function pointer in global function:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    void FuncA(void);
    ...
}
void GlobalFunc(void)
{
    typedef void(ClassA::*MemberFnPtr)(void);
    MemberFnPtr fnPtrA = &ClassA::FuncA;
    ...
}
```

and such pattern worked perfectly as well(as operator:: has a higher priority than operator&)

```
typedef void(ClassA::*MemberFnPtr)(void);
MemberFnPtr fnPtrA = &(ClassA::FuncA);
...
```

However, when I used the latter pattern in a member function, something strange appears `error C2276:"&"`;

I've read something on `std::bind` & `std::function`, and I think that'll be better for me. However, I really wonder what happened when I used the latter pattern in a member function, can anyone help?

Comment: It cannot be used at all, if your compiler allows it it must be an undocumented feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sure it is...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not use parentheses around the name of the member function:

```
MemberFnPtr fnPtrA = &(ClassA::FuncA); // not good
MemberFnPtr fnPtrA = &ClassA::FuncA; // good
```

The C++ Standard mentions this explicitly in section 5.3.1:

> Note: that is, the expression &(qualified-id), where the qualified-id is enclosed in
>   parentheses, does not form an expression of type “pointer to member.”

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this helped a lot. And I wanted to know why the parentheses changed the syntax of the statement(cause with regard to what I've learned, the parentheses mainly did the job of changing priority). So, would you please give me some more suggestions(i.e. some books) on how to understand the issue completely?

Answer (score 1):

You must use this form (as anatolyg said):

```
MemberFnPtr fnPtrA = &ClassA::FuncA;
```

for calling the `fnPtrA` you have to create an object and invoke it as below:

```
ClassA a;
(a.*fnPtrA)();
```

It's a strange syntax since `fnPtrA` is not member of `ClassA`.

Comment: But this form &(ClassA::FuncA) could also be used in global functions...Maybe it's an old style that should've been discarded?

Comment: Standard is explicit about this specific case and says _... does not form an expression of type “pointer to member.”_. So, member methods can not be addressed like that.